# Validar input para receber valor com separador por ponto com jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Preciso que receba apenas valores com esta formatação (20.00)

Resolvido

```html
    <!-- apenas números-->
    <script>
    function somenteNumeros(num) {
        var er = /[^0-9.]/;
        er.lastIndex = 0;
        var campo = num;
        if (er.test(campo.value)) {
          campo.value = "";
        }
    }
    </script>


<input class="form-control input-sm" onkeyup="somenteNumeros(this);" placeholder="valor" maxlength="5" type="text"  ng-model="numero.valor" />
```

Answer (score 1):

A expressão para validar essa formatação é `/\d*(\.\d\d)$/`

Comment: deu certo, aceita com o valor com virtual, mais o aceita letras também, tem como evitar isso? agradeço a sua ajuda

Comment: Mais dai é sua logica da função. Segundo a função que você passou se o valor passar no `test` então você limpa o campo. Tá assim, não tá?

Comment: Tá validando corretamente, o problema é que dar para escrever texto também.

Comment: resolvido! valeu, postei o código na pergunta

Answer (score 0):

Tente algo do tipo:

```
function somenteNumeros() {
        var er = /\d*(\.\d\d)$/;
        var valCampo = document.getElementById('campo').value;
        if (!er.test(valCampo)) {
            document.getElementById('campo').value='';                   
        }
}
```

Para permitir apenas números, você pode fazer algo assim:

adicione uma função parecida com esta:

```
function apenasNum(){
    var kc = event.keyCode;
    if(kc >= 48 && kc <= 57){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

No campo do formulário você adiciona o evento onKeypress chamando a função que você criou:

```
<input type="text"  onKeypress="return apenasNum();">
```

Comment: Tá validando corretamente, o problema é que dar para escrever texto também.

Comment: Veja na resposta, eu editei e adicionei uma outra opção para bloquear letras.

Comment: resolvido! valeu, postei o código na pergunta